# Accessing OpenERP with C#

Tags: c#, database, odoo

We have an OpenERP installation. The web interface is sometimes too restrictive. We would like to write our own desktop application in c# to connect to the openERP database and read some data. To be safe, we will just read some data initially, but then we would like to be able to add products and do some other simple things via our own application.

Is this possible with OpenERP? Can anyone point me to a simple C# application that can connect and read some records out of OpenERP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you'll want to use XMLRPC.  [Here's the link](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/6_22_XML-RPC_web_services/)